# Can I autogenerate ID's with ZK?

Tags: zk, zul

My problem is that I implement multiple times the same row.zul. Now I have an ID error because the row.zul file uses static id's.

In zk 8.0 it is possible to use the tag  but I can't use that because we are here at a very old version (3.6.4). Do you know any possibilities to solve that problem? I need to give the elements ID's because I want to read from them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to autogenerate id's.
They need to be in the correct idScope.

An idscope is marked by the [interface `IdSpace`](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/7.0.2/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/IdSpace.html).
So you need to put the row in a separate idScope, so just wrap a component who implement the `IdSpace` like `window`, `include` or create your own component like `extends Div implements IdScope`.

If you use CSS selectors, remember that you need to alter it a little bit.